# How do I conditionally add a class to a block item inside a repeat loop with Chameleon

Tags: python, pyramid, chameleon, template-tal

I am just getting started with pyramid and chameleon templates.

I have the following code example that renders a site menu.

```
<li tal:repeat="menu view.site_menu">
    <tal:block tal:condition="menu.current">
        <span>${menu.title}</span>
    </tal:block>
    <tal:block tal:condition="not menu.current">
        <span><a href="/${menu.href}">${menu.title}</a></span>
    </tal:block>
</li>
```

It highlights the current page menu item by not making it a link.  I am trying to use bootstrap pill navigation.  I need to conditionally add the class="active" to the `<li>` tag of the active page.

I tried adding a tal:condition to the `<li>` tag:

```
 <li tal:repeat="menu view.site_menu" tal:condition="menu.current" class="active">
    <a href="/${menu.href}">${menu.title}</a>
 </li>
```

but I get the following error:

```
builtins.NameError
NameError: menu

 - Expression: "menu.current"
 - Filename:   H:\eta\eta\eta\templates\global_layout.pt
 - Location:   (line 38: col 57)
 - Source:     ... .site_menu" tal:condition="menu.current" class="active">
                                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

My best guess here is that `menu` is only available *inside* the `tal:repeat` tags.

What is the best way to accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The condition is executed *before* the repeat; you'd normally nest the statements to put the condition on a tag contained in the repeat. However, to put a conditional *attribute*, use `tal:attributes` instead:

```
<li tal:repeat="menu view.site_menu" tal:attributes="class 'active' if menu.current else None">
    <a href="/${menu.href}">${menu.title}</a>
</li>
```

Setting an attribute to `None` removes it from the tag.

Comment: Works perfectly.  I have one question though.  As I understand the docks this will replace the attrib.  Is there anyway to add a class (leaving existing classes intact)?  Note: this is not an issue today, but can see where I might come across this in the future.  I am thinking of some construct similar to `class = class + 'someclass'`

Comment: I normally just list the classes in `tal:attributes`; you cannot reference the original value in the tag from `tal:attributes`. You *can* set things to `default` but that's a sentinel value, you cannot use it in string concatenation, for example.

Comment: To keep your default classes you can use a simple ${..} expansion: class="your default classes${' active' if menu.current else ''}"